# Transfer cell text when selected to uitextfield in a different tableview controller - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to figure out how I can take the current text in the cell that is selected and use it in a uitextfield when I segue to another tableview controller.

Here's my code

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)




    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("addPRTableViewController") as! addPRTableViewController


    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

That's the segue.

Here's my array which if it is cell [0] that is selected I'd like it to fill the uitextfield txtPR with the string.

```
var abExercises = ["Ab Roller", "Crunches", "Flat Lying Bench Raise", "Leg Raises", "Russian Twist", "Weighted Crunch"]
```

Updated Code

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegue"
    {
        let nextScene = segue.destinationViewController as! addPRTableViewController

        if let indexPath = abTable.indexPathForSelectedRow
        {
            let exercise = abExercises[indexPath.row]
            nextScene.txtPR.text = exercise
        }
    }
}
```

Destination tableview controller (addPRTableViewController)

```
import UIKit

class addPRTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var txtPR: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtDesc: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var txtWeight: UITextField!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    txtPR.delegate = self



}







// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return 5
}


func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let maxLength = 25
    let currentString: NSString = textField.text!
    let newString: NSString =
        currentString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    return newString.length <= maxLength
}






//Button Clicked
@IBAction func btnAddTask(sender : UIBarButtonItem){
    if (txtPR.text == ""){
        //Task Title is blank, do not add a record
    } else {
        //add record
        let name: String = txtPR.text!
        let description: String = txtDesc.text!
        let weight: String = txtWeight.text!
        taskMgr.addTask(name, desc: description, weight: weight)

        //dismiss keyboard and reset fields

        self.view.endEditing(true)
        txtPR.text = nil
        txtDesc.text = nil
        txtWeight.text = nil

    }
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView //recast your view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red: 246/255, green: 75/255, blue: 55/255, alpha: 1.0)  //make the text white
}
```

}

Comment: what is your problem? you need send particular `tableviewcell` data to another `tableviewcontroller` page

Answer (score 0):

You should look at initiating your segue through the `prepareForSegue` method.  You would need to create a variable in the destination viewController to hold the data passed to it.

Set up a segue from the UITableViewCell to the destination view controller and give the segue an appropriate identifier.

The use the following method to pass the data when the segue is called by tapping the cell.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueName"
    {
        let nextScene = segue.destinationViewController as! NameOfYourViewController

        if let indexPath = yourTableOutlet.indexPathForSelectedRow
        {
           let exercise = abExercises[indexPath.row]
           nextScene.variableCreatedAtDestination = exercise
        }
     }
}
```

You then do not need to call the segue in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

**Update**

Ok, create a variable in addPRTableViewController called `var prexercise = String()`.  In the original viewcontroller, in the `prepareForSegue`, change `nextScene.txtPR.text = exercise` to `nextScene.prexercise = exercise`.

In the addPRTableViewController, in the `viewDidLoad` (or whenever you want the data to appear), set this `textPR.text = prexercise`.  Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: I put in the code with no errors. My segue is all setup but when I click the cell it doesn't transition. I updated my question with the new code.

Comment: Is the segueIdentifier spelled exactly as you have it set up in the storyboard?

Comment: @NateGrant also using this method to transfer data, the segue needs to be setup from the UITableViewCell, not the viewController.  I am updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: My tableviewcell's are prototype cells. Not static. So how could I set the segue up through that?

Comment: @NateGrant That's fine.  Just Control Left Click drag from the prototype cell to the destination view controller.  Then, whenever any cell is clicked, that segue will trigger.  The data is passed from the logic you put into the if statement identifying that segue.

Comment: Alright it works. Just it's not transferring the text to the uitextfield?

Comment: In your destination view controller, use the variable that you created to receive the data to populate the text field/text view/label.

Comment: Post the code from your destination view controller and I will when I get home in a couple of hours.

Comment: @NateGrant I updated my answer.  Hope you get it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the text directly, you should use a variable to store the data that you want to set to the text field. And then in your `viewDidLoad()` func set the text using that variable. Here is an example:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegue"
    {
        let nextScene = segue.destinationViewController as! addPRTableViewController

        if let indexPath = abTable.indexPathForSelectedRow
        {
            let exercise = abExercises[indexPath.row]
            nextScene.txt = exercise
            }
        }
    }
```

Destination tableview controller (addPRTableViewController)

```
class addPRTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var txtPR: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtDesc: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var txtWeight: UITextField!

var txt:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        txtPR.delegate = self
        txtPR.text = txt
    }
```

Hope this helps. :)